# CSRF Token in Master/Slave environment

Tags: spring-security, csrf

I've implemented a REST service using Spring web services, with CSRF security enabled in spring-security.xml, as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd">
    <security:http>
        <security:csrf/>
    </security:http>
</beans>
```

This application is deployed on two tomcat 7.0 servers in a master/slave setup, with apache used as a load balancer.

Some requests are being rejected by the server, throwing a security exception that the CSRF token is invalid.

I think a request with a valid CSRF token for the master server is being redirected to the slave, and vice versa, which is causing the exception. Can you configure security so that a valid token for either server is accepted by the other?

Answer (score 0):

By default the CSRF Token is stored inside the HttpSession.

This means that you need to have the HttpSession replicated over. One easy way to do this is using [Spring Session](http://projects.spring.io/spring-session/).

The other question you can ask yourself is "Are you using the rest service from a web browser?" If not, then you can remove CSRF protection.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, the problem was actually with the load balancer. We've changed the configuration so that a user's session sticks to one server, and this has resolved the issue